# Error : Application run failed , trying to implement Service discovery Eureka

Tags: java, netflix-eureka

I have a very simple demo application which I am using to register with Eureka server. But I am getting the below error. I have been able to successfully register another demo application but this one fails:

This is the error message:

> 12:29:07.678 [restartedMain] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.context.logging.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/test/Downloads/demorest/target/classes/]
>   12:29:07.728 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.jboss.logging - Logging Provider: org.jboss.logging.Log4j2LoggerProvider
>   12:29:07.729 [background-preinit] INFO org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.14.Final
>   12:29:07.736 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraversableResolvers - Cannot find javax.persistence.Persistence on classpath. Assuming non JPA 2 environment. All properties will per default be traversable.
>   12:29:07.741 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml for XML based Validator configuration.
>   12:29:07.743 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via TCCL
>   12:29:07.744 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ResourceLoaderHelper - Trying to load META-INF/validation.xml via Hibernate Validator's class loader
>   12:29:07.744 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.xml.config.ValidationXmlParser - No META-INF/validation.xml found. Using annotation based configuration only.
>   12:29:07.939 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator - Loaded expression factory via original TCCL
>   12:29:07.944 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator as ValidatorFactory-scoped message interpolator.
>   12:29:07.944 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.TraverseAllTraversableResolver as ValidatorFactory-scoped traversable resolver.
>   12:29:07.945 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.ExecutableParameterNameProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped parameter name provider.
>   12:29:07.945 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.DefaultClockProvider as ValidatorFactory-scoped clock provider.
>   12:29:07.945 [background-preinit] DEBUG org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl - HV000234: Using org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.scripting.DefaultScriptEvaluatorFactory as ValidatorFactory-scoped script evaluator factory.
>   12:29:08.513 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
>       at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:68)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:75)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:347)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
>       at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
>       at com.example.rest.demorest.DemorestApplication.main(DemorestApplication.java:15)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

The same project can start fine without the Eureka in place.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example.rest</groupId>
<artifactId>demorest</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>demorest</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties:

```
    spring.application.name=demorest
    eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Application class:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemorestApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DemorestApplication.class, args);

    String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    //Arrays.sort(beanNames);

    for(String name : beanNames)
        System.out.println(name);
}

}
```

Comment: Most probably you are running with wrong dependencies version. Check the error:

ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.([Ljava/lang/Object;)V at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:161) at

Comment: Thank you pringi. This worked for me after adding dependency management section for cloud. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer given by [Ben G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55342713/error-application-run-failed-trying-to-implement-service-discovery-eureka#comment97416489_55342713), Spring Cloud and Spring Boot should have compatible versions which can be found [here](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) under *Table 1. Release train Spring Boot compatibility*.

For example: Spring Boot 2.6.1 and Spring Cloud 2021.0.0 can be used together as following:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2021.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```